# React: Deep requiring is deprecated as of uuid, Please require the top-level module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, uuid

my React app successfully shows the button however receiving this error.

index.js:1 Deep requiring like `const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');` is deprecated as of uuid@7.x. Please require the top-level module when using the Node.js CommonJS module or use ECMAScript Modules when bundling for the browser

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
import uuid from 'uuid/v4';

class ShoppingList extends Component {
    state = {
        items: [
            { id: uuid(), name: 'Eggs' },
            { id: uuid(), name: 'Milk' },
            { id: uuid(), name: 'Steak' },
            { id: uuid(), name: 'Water' },
        ]
    }

    render() {
        const { items } = this.state;
        return (
            <Container>
                <Button 
                 color="dark"
                 style={{marginBottom: '2rem'}}
                 onClick={() => {
                    const name = prompt('Enter Item');
                    if (name) {
                        this.setState(state => ({
                           items: [...state.items, { id: uuid(), name }] 
                        }));
                    }
                }}
                >Add Item</Button>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default ShoppingList;
```

- I tried to use 'import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';   uuidv4();'
- however my button would not show up and i would get error:
- Uncaught ReferenceError: uuid is not defined
- Perhaps i am meant to be getting this error? and everything is currently working fine?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This has changed after recent update to library and now you may import uuid, as per library description :

"As of uuid@7 this library now provides ECMAScript modules builds, which allow packagers like Webpack and Rollup to do "tree-shaking" to remove dead code. Instead, use the import"

```
import { v4 as uuid_v4 } from "uuid";
uuid_v4()
```

... or for CommonJS:

```
const { v4: uuid_v4 } = require('uuid');
uuid_v4();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [react-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-uuid) instead

```sh
npm i react-uuid
```

usage

```
import uuid from "react-uuid";
```

---

Try it online:

[image: Edit polished-silence-u7ut6]