# uuid - default export (ReactJS - JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have here problem which is regarding ID`s, the basic idea was to generate ID for alerts, and for that I was using uuid library, but when I used the library I get error which is saying next:

```
./src/action/alert.js
Attempted import error: 'uuid' does not contain a default export (imported as 'uuid').
```

here is code from alert.js file:

```
import uuid from 'uuid';
import { SET_ALERT, REMOVE_ALERT } from './types';

export const setAlert = (msg, alertType, timeout = 5000) => dispatch => {
    const id = uuid.v4();
    dispatch({
        type: SET_ALERT,
        payload: { msg, alertType, id }
    });

    setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: REMOVE_ALERT, payload: id }), timeout);
};
```

I tried many solutions but some of them fixes this error but creates a warning which is problem again, so do you guys have any idea what is solution for this problem?

Best regards,
Sanady.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60721008/react-deep-requiring-is-deprecated-as-of-uuid-please-require-the-top-level-mod/60721159#60721159

Answer (score 5):

Jakub's answer is correct and you can see why in the uuid documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid).

Essentially, you need to specify in your import what method you want to use. For instance if you needed timestamp ids, you'd use v1 and that'd look like this:

```
import { v1 as uuid } from 'uuid';
uuid();
```

and the return would be something like:

```
'2c5ea4c0-4067-11e9-8b2d-1b9d6bcdbbfd'
```

The syntax you're using might be from an earlier version of UUID.

Answer (score 1):

Try that

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
uuid();
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this solution, but after code compiled problem get complicated, which means that I have problem with var ID: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.